# Replace time column with the current time

Tags: text-processing

I have data in file portals.csv like

filename is **portals.csv**

```
ip,time,name
1.1.1.1,2018-08-15 11:05:28:268813353,1.13.0-0007
1.1.1.2,2018-08-16 11:05:32:016469121,1.13.0-0007
1.1.1.3,2018-08-16 11:06:42:316469121,1.13.0-0007
1.1.2.5,2018-08-16 11:15:52:416469121,1.13.0-0007
```

Need the output like this, the time column data should take the current time with different second for each and every rows

```
ip,time,name
1.1.1.1,2018-08-17 15:00:01,1.13.0-0007
1.1.1.2,2018-08-17 15:00:02,1.13.0-0007
1.1.1.3,2018-08-17 15:00:03,1.13.0-0007
1.1.2.5,2018-08-17 15:00:04,1.13.0-0007
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an option using GNU Awk, using `NR` to increment an epoch timestamp passed in from the `date` command:

```
gawk -F, -v ts="$(date +%s)" '
  BEGIN{OFS = FS} 
  NR > 1 {$2 = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", ts + NR - 1)}
1' portals.csv
ip,time,name
1.1.1.1,2018-08-17 09:47:17,1.13.0-0007
1.1.1.2,2018-08-17 09:47:18,1.13.0-0007
1.1.1.3,2018-08-17 09:47:19,1.13.0-0007
1.1.2.5,2018-08-17 09:47:20,1.13.0-0007
```

See [The GNU Awk User's Guide: Time functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Time-Functions)

---

Similar approach in Perl:

```
perl -MPOSIX -F, -lne '
  BEGIN{$ts = time()};
  $F[1] = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", localtime($ts + $. - 1)) if $. > 1; 
  print join ",", @F
' portals.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with date / time fields never is an easy thing, so for a full blown solution, way more effort must be spent. If your input file has less than 60 lines, try

```
awk -F, -vDT="$(date +"%F %T")" 'NR > 1 {sub (/:..$/, sprintf (":%02d", NR-1), DT); $2 = DT} 1' OFS=, file
ip,time,name
1.1.1.1,2018-08-17 12:47:01,1.13.0-0007
1.1.1.2,2018-08-17 12:47:02,1.13.0-0007
1.1.1.1,2018-08-17 12:47:03,1.13.0-0007
1.1.1.2,2018-08-17 12:47:04,1.13.0-0007
1.1.1.3,2018-08-17 12:47:05,1.13.0-0007
1.1.2.5,2018-08-17 12:47:06,1.13.0-0007
```

or, slightly shorter,

```
awk -F, -vDT="$(date +"%F %H:%M")" 'NR > 1 {$2 = DT sprintf (":%02d", NR-1)} 1' OFS=, file
```

**EDIT:** For your additional request to extend this for up to 99 lines in the input file, try

```
awk -F, -vDT="$(date +"%F %H:")" 'NR > 1 {$2 = DT sprintf ("%02d:%02d", int((NR-1)/60), (NR-1)%60)} 1' OFS=, file
```

Comment: Thanks RudiC, it is working but the file is having more than 60 lines, so it is showing seconds value after 59th rows showing incorrect. Can't we increase the value as time, like after 00:00:59 it show 00:01:00 likewise for all the coming new rows.

Comment: Yes, and after 3600 seconds roll over to the hours, and after 86400 seconds to days. What to do at year end, and what in leap years? There are algorithms dealing with date / time arithmetics in these and other fora.

Comment: The total rows coming in file is 99 only, is there any way so that it will work like that.

Comment: Any attempt / idea / thought from your side?